# Error thrown but not caught in useEffect try-catch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to react. Here I am fetching data from an API and checking if there are null values present in the one of the attributes. If so, the code throws a 'Module not found' error. The error is being thrown but not caught in the catch block. The log in the catch block does not show up when the error is thrown. What am i doing wrong??

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try { 
        const res = await fetch(url);
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw Error("Unable to request data for this resource");
        }
        if (isMounted) {
          const data = await res.json();
          if (data.modInfo === null) {
            throw Error("Module not found");
          }
          setmodInfo(data.modInfo);
          setIsLoading(false);
          setError(null);
        }
      } catch(err) {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setError(err.message);
        console.log('err', err.message);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, [url]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with the order of state updates on `isLoading` and `error` as well as my conditions for conditional rendering of child components.

In `useEffect()`:

```
setIsLoading(false);
setError(err.message);
console.log('err', err.message);
```

In return statement of the component:

```
  return (
    <>
      {isLoading && <h2>Loading...</h2>}
      {error && <h2>Module not found</h2>}
      {!isLoading && !error && (
      ...
  )
```

My guess is that once `isLoading` was set to `true` the third condition passed before `error` could be updated since state updates are asynchronous. Fixed this by updating `error` before `isLoading` in the catch block and checking for `error` first in the render.

Fixed `useEffect()`:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try { 
        const res = await fetch(url);
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw Error("Unable to request data for this resource");
        }
        if (isMounted) {
          const data = await res.json();
          if (data.modInfo === null) {
            console.log("found null")
            throw Error("Module not found");
          }
          setmodInfo(data.modInfo);
          setError(null);
          setIsLoading(false);
        }
      } catch(err) {
        setError(err.message);
        console.log(err.message);
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, [url]);
```

Fixed return statement:

```
  return (
    <>
      {error && <h2>Module not found</h2>}
      {isLoading && <h2>Loading...</h2>}
      {!isLoading && !error && (
      ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Might it work the way you intend if you make `isMounted` stateful?

Move this out of the `useEffect`:

```
let isMounted = true;
```

And change to:

```
const [isMounted, setIsMounted] useState(true);
```

And change this:

```
return () => {
  isMounted = false;
};
```

to:

```
return () => {
  setIsMounted(false);
};
```